# jQuery not working inside ajax loaded div withen same page

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, load

I've been after this for days with no luck & tried questions/answeres here but couldn't figure out how to fix mine (tried changing one .live with .click in the code but no luck).
This is what I have/changed in the jquery.ajaxy.js (there maybe other places in the code I need to change but when I tried, ajaxy didn't work right so I'm doing something wrong here. **This code may not even be part of the solution because its the jQuery inside the ajax loaded div that doesn't work**)

```
$.fn.preventDefaultOnClick = $.fn.preventDefaultOnClick || function(){

        //original
        //return $(this).click(function(event){

        return $(this).live('click', function(event){
           event.preventDefault();
           return false;
    });
};
```

My Test link(s) at http://eddiepotros.com/test/

- Click **About**, the keywords **DESIGNER** & **ONE STOP SHOP** should show jquery styled tooltips but it doesn't work unless you go to the page itself http://eddiepotros.com/test/pages/about.html then it works (loading jquery there too but even if I remove it, still won't work)
- Click on **Portfolio**, same problem. jQuery code not working on that page/div unless you go directly to it eddiepotros.com/test/pages/portfolio.php

Any suggestions please??
Just to be clear, I don't know if the code I posted is what can solve my problem. I'm just guessing but it doesn't seem like it's doing anything as per the first 2 comments here.
**My problem is no jQuery can be called from that ajax loaded div**

I'VE BEEN TRYING THIS FOR A LONG TIME WITH NO LUCK STILL!

Answer (score 0):

`return this.live('click', function(event){`

JQuery object is implied?

Comment: I did but it didn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.fn.preventDefaultOnClick = function(){

   return $(this).live('click', function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
          });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the JavaScript on the about.html

```
$('#about a[href][title]').qtip({
  content: {
     text: true // Use each elements title attribute
  },
  hide: { /*when: 'inactive',*/ delay: 800, effect: 'fade' },
  show: { effect: 'grow' },
  style: 'cream' 
});
```

at the bottom of the HTML instead of in the document.Ready section.

Comment: This doesn't work too. When you run the code by itself
http://localhost/eddiepotros/pages/about.html it works as is buy it's within the div it's still not working

Comment: Opps sorry i meant http://eddiepotros.com/test/pages/about.html the tool tip works there. However, when the page is being loaded by ajaxy in the div, jquery inside that div does work. other javascript does though.

Comment: If you have found the solution please post

Answer (score 0):

Revert any changes you have done before to make the the tooltip to work.

in the about.html
 remove the document.ready.

just put the code at the end of about.html page.

```
<script>

// By suppling no content attribute, the library uses each elements title attribute by default
   $('#about a[href][title]').qtip({
      content: {
         text: true // Use each elements title attribute
      },
      hide: { /*when: 'inactive',*/ delay: 800, effect: 'fade' },
      show: { effect: 'grow' },
      style: 'cream' // cream, dark, green, light, red, blue
   });

    //effects such as fade, slide, grow   
   // NOTE: You can even omit all options and simply replace the regular title tooltips like so:
   // $('#content a[href]').qtip();
</script>
```

It should work. Lemme know if it doesn't

Comment: I tried this and just minified the script (removed comments and other things) and put it at the bottom but **it still didn't work**.

I think the problem is not with that page itself (maybe relative linking of script is an issue) but the main problem is the index page loading the ajax div. Something about that is what's causing the jQuery not to work on the loaded pages. I just don't know how to fix it. I tried all I know already!